# Can I call some method randomly in C# (Unity)?

Tags: c#, random, methods

I wanna call some method randomly. Can I do it in C#?

I tried to some trials like using array, but I failed.

Here is what I've tried:

```
public void OnClick()
{

   Example1 a = new Example1();
   Example2 b = new Example2();

   object[] RandomArray = { "a", "b" };

   Random rand = new Random();
   int number = rand.Next(2);
}

public class Example1 : Example_PlayingType2
{
   public void Random1()
   {

   }
}

public class Example2 : Example_PlayingType2
{
   public void Random2()
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: what dd you try exactly?

Comment: oh, ok sorry guys. i posted the codes what i tried.

Comment: Do you want to call a random method from a list of methods, or do you want to call a single method at random times? Please explain what you mean by "randomly".

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to call a random function would be to use an `if` or `switch` statement, like this:

```
class Bar
{
    public void OnClick()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int number = rand.Next(2);
        if(number == 0)
            foo.Random1();
        if(number == 1)
            foo.Random2();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public void Random1()
    {

    }
    public void Random2()
    {

    }
}
```

Putting both random methods in one class makes sense if they're related to that class. Of course you can instantiate two different classes and use those in the if statement. That all depends on what makes sense with your architecture, so please edit my code according to your needs.

Note: As Johnny mentioned in his comment, you'll want to move the `Random` into a field at some point.

Comment: It is not a good practice to create `Random` each time, it is better to have it as a field, initialized only once.

Comment: You're right, I put it like this because the OP doesn't seem to be very familiar with programming in C# yet and I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible - hence my approach with the if statement rather than going into actions.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach, a bit flexibile one where you could register different actions:

```
public class Bar
{
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly IDictionary<int, Action> _actions = new Dictionary<int, Action>();

    public void OnClick()
        => _actions[_random.Next(_actions.Count)]?.Invoke();

    public void Register(Action action)
        => _actions[_actions.Count] = action;
}
```

and then you could use it as:

```
var b = new Bar();
var foo = new Foo();

b.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("a"));
b.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("b"));
b.Register(foo.Random1);
b.Register(foo.Random2);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    b.OnClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do so is to use a `Dictionary`. Add the `string` and respective `method` to the `Dictionary` and then user `Invoke()` to call them based on the random string selected.